# Adding default value for old rows MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I want to add a new attribute of type `int` in a Model and I want to set
this attribute in the old rows in the database to be 1 instead of the
default `int` value 0 .

I am also using code first I tried `[DefaultValue(1)]` but it didn't
work. Is there another way ?

Comment: Are you using Migrations? You can modify the DbMigration for that column and specify the default value. However, you probably also want to set the value in your model's ctor.

Comment: Yes I am using migration and I know that I can set it in the migration file but I want to know if there is another way through the Model itself

Comment: So you want to change the old values without modifying the constraint?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a constructor

```
  public YourClass()
    { 
        val = 1;       
    }

   puclic int val {get; set;}
```

Comment: This solution will work only for the new objects but not for the existing objects in the database

Comment: for exiting you got to do it in a database level